# Chiral categories versus braided monoidal categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory

Let $X$ be a curve over $\mathbf{C}$. As I understand from the 2008 Talbot notes, a **chiral category** on $X$ consists of a crystal of categories  on the Ran space $\mathrm{Ran}(X)$ (see these [notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/GL/Ran.pdf) of Gaitsgory) together with factorization data: that is, the category associated to $X^I$ should be the same as the $I$-fold tensor product of the category associated to $X$, when restricted to the locus where the coordinates are distinct. Factorization spaces over $X$, such as the affine Grassmannian, give one source of chiral categories.

As I understand, the notion of a chiral category is supposed to be the algebro-geometric analog of a factorization algebra (in categories) in topology, as defined in ch. 5 of Lurie's "Higher Algebra" (using an operad $\mathbf{E}_M$ associated to $M$, but equivalently cosheaves on the topological version of the Ran space).   There, it is proved that locally constant factorization algebras over euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^n$ are equivalent to $\mathbf{E}_n$-algebras. So, chiral categories, especially over $\mathbf{A}^1$, are supposed to be a version of $\mathbf{E}_2$-algebras in the algebro-geometric setting.

I'm looking for a precise comparison statement (rather than an analogy) along these lines between the algebro-geometric and topological pictures. In particular, given a chiral category (e.g., over $\mathbf{A}^1$), I'd like to know:

1) Is there a natural way to extract an $\mathbf{E}_2$-category by taking sections over $\mathbf{A}^1$?

2) If so, what is the formula for the $\mathbf{E}_2$-tensor product?

The example I have in mind, which I would like to understand, is the tensor structure on the geometric Satake category constructed in [Mirkovich-Vilonen](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401222).

**Edit:** It seems like the construction in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5314) of Richarz is based upon the following. Given two objects in the category over $X$ (which here is equivariant perverse sheaves on the affine Grassmannian), one forms their external tensor product in the category over the complement of the diagonal in $X \times X$ (which makes sense) and then intermediate extends to obtain an object over $X \times X$, and then applies a vanishing cycles functor to obtain a new object over $X$. In what generality can something like this be done, and why should such a construction yield a (braided) monoidal structure?

Comment: What does it mean for a crystal of categories to be quasi-coherent?

Comment: @S.Carnahan : You are right, perhaps this is part of the definition.

Comment: I think it's not quite right to think of a chiral algebra as an $E_2$ algebra.  The latter should give examples of the former (up to some framing, perhaps), but chiral algebras should not, in general, be "locally constant".  Think about a much less categorical setting of functions.  Locally constant functions are very different from holomorphic functions.  Or am I misunderstanding the notion of "chiral algebra" --- is there a "de Rham" that I missed somewhere?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: Yes, I believe that the "crystal" datum (for a chiral category) is supposed to be the algebro-geometric analog of local (or, at least, infinitesimal) constancy.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: there's a notion of quasicoherent sheaf of categories --- locally it's given as a module category over the monoidal category of quasicoherent sheaves. You can then ask for a crystal structure (descent to de Rham space, I assume we're in characteristic zero) if you will. The definitive reference is arXiv:1306.4304

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: unital chiral (or factorization) algebras automatically come with a de Rham (or crystal) structure.

Comment: @AkhilMathew: I don't see why one should expect to "extract" something locally constant from something crystalline. Categories are not the issue: the analog would be extracting a local system from an algebraic D-module. There's a condition we could ask for the D-module, that it be a flat vector bundle, and then (analytically) we can apply Riemann-Hilbert and get a local system. But I don't know if there's a very well behaved "integration" functor on D-modules (something like extending to infinite order differential operators) which would "extract" a local system from one.

Comment: In the Gaitsgory-Lurie Talbot story I think you're in the former setting --- you have a chiral category (coming from representations of Kac-Moody algebras) which happens to be integrable, so after Riemann-Hilbert you get a braided tensor category. Same in the geometric Satake setting, you have algebraic and topological chiral categories related by Riemann-Hilbert. The formula for the E_2 structure comes from trivilaizing your flat category over the disc, writing a monoidal structure using collisions of two points along a ray then describing the monodromy as those points braid in the disc.

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi: Could you elaborate on the condition of "integrability" which enables one to obtain the E_2-category?

Comment: In particular, I'd be curious if it applies in the geometric Satake setting as well (though I'd also like to understand the E_2-structure in the affine Kac-Moody case).

Comment: Actually, it looks like you're indicating it does apply in the geometric Satake setting -- so I suppose what I'm looking for is a description (or reference for) the version of Riemann-Hilbert that applies here.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you want to consider crystals of categories where all associated D-modules (eg Homs of objects) are actually flat vector bundles, hence you can apply usual R-H. More precisely you have three sym monoidal categories, Loc_B, Loc_dR and D (local systems, flat vector bundles and D-modules). Module categories for the first two are the same via R-H. A module for D is "integrable" if it's induced from a Loc_dR-module, hence we can attach to it a Loc_B-module. (This is a garbled version of a formulation of Sam Raskin.)

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi: Sounds like the statement I was looking for. I'll ask Sam about this further when I next see him. Thanks.

Comment: I think much is said in the folklore but you won't find much written down. At least I know of three big groups working in Boston, Chicago and Paris trying to sort these things. In particular, the AG analog of Topological Factorization Algebra does exist (and predates the topological one) and is a Factorization algebra in Beilinson-Drinfeld. E_2 algebras are locally constant (or constructible) such algebras, their AG counterpart correspond to what are called Topological Vertex algebras. Presumably RH goes from the AG side to the top. side and this has been claimed by many to be done.

Comment: Continuing: little is known for general vertex algebras or general factorization algebras in the Beilinson-Drinfeld case. Namely those which will not come from holonomic D-modules (which is the right finiteness and locally constant condition in the AG side). I've heard many times and from many that applying Chiral Homology and then RH one should obtain a factorization algebra. However, there are some subtleties involved since analitification does not preserve the chiral operations for general D-modules (quasi-coherent as O-mod).